# How to implement <web services @path> in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to implement a path-like in servlets ? for example

```
@WebServlet("/root/*")
public class Example extends HttpServlet{

@Path("/node1")
    public String method1(){
doSomething();
}
    @Path("/node1/node2")
    public String method2 (){
doAnotherthing();
}
}
```

and so , if I wrote in the URL  ... /root/node1 it would execute method1
and if I wrote /root/node1/node2 it would execute method2